# add capacity using LVM system

Tags: linux, partitioning, virtual-machine, redhat-enterprise-linux, lvm

my current /home directory is lack of storage so i want to add capacity to LV. want to confirm if my execution plan will not distroy the existing system.

Here is the current disk status:

```
df -h
/dev/mapper/vg_root-lv_home           4.0G  4.0G   86M  98% /home
```

here is the current PVS, VGS, LVS:

```
sudo pvs
  PV         VG         Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree
  /dev/sda3  vg_root    lvm2 a--   <59.00g 4.00m
  /dev/sdb   vg_app_sdb lvm2 a--  <600.00g    0 

sudo vgs
      VG         #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree
      vg_app_sdb   1   1   0 wz--n- <600.00g    0 
      vg_root      1   8   0 wz--n-  <59.00g 4.00m

sudo lvs
  LV               VG         Attr       LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lv_app_sdb       vg_app_sdb -wi-ao---- <600.00g                                                    
  lv_home          vg_root    -wi-ao----    4.00g                                                    
  lv_root          vg_root    -wi-ao----   20.99g                                                    
  lv_swap          vg_root    -wi-ao----    4.00g                                                    
  lv_tmp           vg_root    -wi-ao----    2.00g                                                    
  lv_var           vg_root    -wi-ao----   10.00g                                                    
  lv_var_log       vg_root    -wi-ao----   10.00g                                                    
  lv_var_log_audit vg_root    -wi-ao----    6.00g                                                    
  lv_var_tmp       vg_root    -wi-ao----    2.00g

lsblk
NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                            8:0    0   60G  0 disk 
├─sda1                         8:1    0  512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                         8:2    0  512M  0 part /boot
└─sda3                         8:3    0   59G  0 part 
  ├─vg_root-lv_root          253:0    0   21G  0 lvm  /
  ├─vg_root-lv_swap          253:1    0    4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─vg_root-lv_home          253:3    0    4G  0 lvm  /home
  ├─vg_root-lv_tmp           253:4    0    2G  0 lvm  /tmp
  ├─vg_root-lv_var_tmp       253:5    0    2G  0 lvm  /var/tmp
  ├─vg_root-lv_var_log       253:6    0   10G  0 lvm  /var/log
  ├─vg_root-lv_var_log_audit 253:7    0    6G  0 lvm  /var/log/audit
  └─vg_root-lv_var           253:8    0   10G  0 lvm  /var
sdb                            8:16   0  600G  0 disk 
└─vg_app_sdb-lv_app_sdb      253:2    0  600G  0 lvm  /app
sr0                           11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

and below is my execution plan:

1. check current status of disk

   df -h
2. create Physical Volume (PV)

   sudo pvcreate /dev/sdc
3. identify Volume Group (VG) and Logical Volume (LV)

   sudo vgs / sudo lvs
4. add PV to VG

   sudo vgextend vg_root /dev/sdc
5. extend the existing LV

   sudo lvextend -L +600G /dev/vg_root/lv_home
6. extend filesystem

   xfs_growfs /dev/vg_root/lv_home

please tell me if this plan is go or no go